# How to download mysql driver manually

Tags: go

Is there any way to download mysql driver mannually for ubuntu(ver:16.04)? Seems our server has blocking access to the github.com, so I need deploy mysql driver by hand.

The `go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` command haven't any response for a while then exit it. I've already installed git & go.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: `go get` just wraps git. You can always clone a repo by hand or unpack a source release yourself.

Comment: go get is also silent... have you tried `ls $GOPATH/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` yet?

Comment: thank u guys, It's work for clone repo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$ mkdir $GOPATH/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
$ pushd $GOPATH/src/github.com/go-sql-driver
$ git clone https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql.git
$ popd
```